# Collect a list of pairs into a map

Tags: groovy

How can we collect a list of lists of value pairs into a map where said pairs are transformed into `key:value` entries in the map, as in:

```
a = [[1,11], [2,22], [3,33]]
b = ...?
assert b == [1:11, 2:22, 3:33]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collectEntries%28%29) works with a pair list, you can just do

```
def b = a.collectEntries()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def b = a.collectEntries {[(it.get(0)): it.get(1)]}
```

Comment: Thanks. You know, the confusing part for me is the requirement of the pair of parentheses around the first element - or just the break down of the syntax.

Comment: @BaselShishani yes, they look unusual, especially for java programmers

Comment: @BaselShishani they are needed because the keys in maps are used as literal strings. `[ it : 90 ]` creates a map with a key `"it"`, whereas `[ (it) : 90 ]` creates a map with the key being the value in the `it` var

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collectEntries%28%29), which turns Iterables (like Lists) into Maps:

```
a = [[1,11], [2,22], [3,33]]
b = a.collectEntries { [ (it.first()) : it.last() ] }
assert b == [1:11, 2:22, 3:33]
```